# Javascript compiled files to import css instead of scss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, sass, babeljs

I am distributing some compiled files, which means from this tree

```
- src
  - components
    - Button
      - index.jsx
      - button.scss
```

I compiled to this tree:

```
- lib
  - components
    - Button
      - index.js
      - button.css
```

The problem I have is that babel does not change the extension of the required style files to css.
In my `Button/index.jsx` file I import the style like this:

`import './button.scss'`

This means in my compiled javascript file I still find

`require('./button.scss');`

while obviously this file is not present in the new tree, because the extension is now css.
Is there a babel way to change the imports name/extentions and is this even recommendable? At what time of the compilation should this happen?

Comment: please add your wepack file

Comment: Why? I am not using webpack for distributing, I am just compiling with babel and sass.

Comment: My bad, thought you use webpack

Answer (score 0):

Hope you wrote your JSX file like this :

**src/index.jsx:**

import styles from './button.scss' or require("./button.scss")

and the transpiled js file under lib

**lib/index.js:**

import styles from './button.scss' or require("./button.scss")

and your transpiling those JSX files by using babel cli, is that right ?

You can achieve this by following steps:

**Step 1 :**

Include all .scss under main.scss file like below:

main.scss

```
.my-component {  
  @import 'utils/all';
  @import 'base/all';
  @import 'components/all';
}
```

and placed it as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/stylesheets/main.css">
```

in your html. Make a common/global css style guide for all components.

**Step 2:**

if your not intended to use webpack, you can simply place dest css location

```
import styles from './button.css'
```

in src/JSX itself.

**Step 3:**

Using webpack the best way to go about this would probably to use a loader chain 
 such as **style!css!sass** for your .scss imports which would allow you to simply import and use the styles within
  your React components in the following manner:

```
import styles from './button.scss';

export default props => <button className={styles.button} />
```

I'll be ready to adapt if anything better than this approach.

read more at : [react-sass-babel-webpack](https://medium.com/@srinisoundar/setting-up-environment-for-react-sass-es2015-babel-with-webpack-2f77445129)

Comment: I am not using webpack for distributing and I want to import the sass files in my component files. I changed the question with some more info, hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: yes @feychou, if you want to import sass in your component those are the three steps you need. babel does not change the extension of the required style files to css, instead you need webpack to configure it there's no way of babel changes the style extension, try webpack once with the above answer provided

Comment: I want to distribute a library, I do not want to go through webpack because I do not want to bundle it. Also I am not using css modules, your answer implies that I am. I also do not want to have the host including my third party css as shown in your example.

Comment: one way to change the extension is to use a babel plugin that does that once the compilation has gone through but I would like to find a more reliable way if it exists.

Comment: just checked it,there's a plugin to change extension and i'm not sure about how reliable it is. I am configuring sass/scss/css through webpack and it's work like a charm as the documentation suggests.

Comment: I do use webpack to bundle the hosting application, but I am distributing via node specs, that is why I do not use webpack.

Comment: If i got some reliable way to do that without webpack, definitely will share here

Comment: I just want to know, how you imported those styles in your jsx file without css-modules and webpack only with babel. Let's consider there's only .css extension, how you have imported those styles in JSX and made it work @feychou